# Is there a way to automate the process of comparing data by finding the max value and expressing all other values as a percentage of the max value?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

So I have sets of data I want to compare using a histogram graph or a radar graph.
The process is as follows:

Once you've done your tables with your data.

1. Find the max value in every column.
2. express all other column values as =this_column/max_column
3. do your graph

I know it looks simple enough, but I have 50 lines to go through and I'd really like to know if there is a function I could just scroll through the whole thing or something.

Here is an illustration of what I have done by hand:

[image: Work by hand]

And here is a fraction of what I have to do still:

[image: 1 of 5 blocks like it]

Comment: Please don't use a single question for multiple requests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out this was easily solved by using the MAX function to create a new column that contained the MAX value of each row.

Then all the rows can just be their value/max value.
Using the $, this can be dragged everywhere on the other rows and columns.